# In Rails, how to see all the "path" and "url" methods added by Rails's routing? (update: using Rails console)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**[update: by not using `rake routes`, just to understand Rails console a little more]**

It seems like inside of "rails console" for Rails 3, we can use `controller`, but in Rails 2.2 or 2.3, we need to use `@controller`

And in Rails 3, we can print out all the routes added by Rails routing for a scaffold `foo`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > puts controller.public_methods.grep(/path|url/).grep(/foo/).sort.join("\n")
edit_foo_path
edit_foo_url
foo_path
foo_url
foos_path
foos_url
new_foo_path
new_foo_url
```

but on Rails 2.3.8, it gives a bunch of `formatted_foos_path`, etc, and gives nothing for Rails 2.2.2.  How to make it print out for Rails 2.3.8 and 2.2.2?

---

Details for Rails 2.3.8:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > puts @controller.public_methods.grep(/path|url/).grep(/foo/).sort.join("\n")
formatted_edit_foo_path
formatted_edit_foo_url
formatted_foo_path
formatted_foo_url
formatted_foos_path
formatted_foos_url
formatted_new_foo_path
formatted_new_foo_url
```

Comment: what makes the question deserve a "-1" vote?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

### Rails 3.x–6.x

```rb
Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helper_names
```

### Rails 2.x

```rb
helpers = Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helpers
```

This will get you all the named route methods that were created.  Then you can do `helpers.map(&:to_s)`, and whatever regex you want to get your foo versions

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helpers.select {|h| h.to_s =~ /some_search/ }`

Comment: In Rails 5 you need `helpers = Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helper_names`

Comment: The `helpers` method has been removed in new versions of Rails. It's now `helper_names`

This works in rails 5.1:

`Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helper_names`

Comment: In Rails 6 this prints: `["rails_info_properties_path", "rails_info_routes_path", "rails_info_path", "rails_mailers_path", "rails_info_properties_url", "rails_info_routes_url", "rails_info_url", "rails_mailers_url"]`. Not helpful.

Comment: Edited the question to include more recent `helper_names` method.

Comment: @thisismydesign Are you calling `helpers` or `helper_names`? When I call `helper_names` I get what I would expect (basically `routes.rb` mapped to snake-case `_path` and `_url` strings).

Answer (score 30):

or load up `localhost_path/rails/info/routes` in your browser.

Comment: Works for Rails 6.

Answer (score 8):

Well in Rails 4, I use `rake routes`. Is it that you need?

Comment: rake routes does not always list the associated url helper method.

Comment: You cannot see the names of the `*_url` `*_path` helpers there.

Answer (score 2):

**Rails >= 6.1**

I just upgraded an app to 6.1.4 and noticed that `rake routes` no longer works.

Instead we can run `bin/rails routes`

> To get a complete list of the available routes in your application, visit `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` in your browser while your server is running in the development environment. You can also execute the `bin/rails routes` command in your terminal to produce the same output.

Docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes