# How to get raw route of named helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get   'order/:order_id/add_item/:item_id' => 'order#item_add', as: :order_add_item
end
```

I can call `order_add_item_url(order_id: something, item_id: some_other)` and it will return `order/something/add_item/some_other`.

My question is, can i get the "raw" URL? So i want to get something like `order_add_item_url` returns `order/:order_id/add_item/:item_id`

I have digged into Rails' Journey internals, and get field something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.named_routes.routes[:order_add_item].path.source
=>  "\\A/pos/order/([^/.?]+)/add_item/([^/.?]+)(?:\\.([^/.?]+))?\\Z"
```

But it strips down the "original" version of the path i wrote in the `routes`. There is no `:item_id` and `:order_id`

I am using Rails 4.2.

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5346350/733721). It uses `Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helpers(&:to_s)`. That probably gives all routes, but it should be easy to figure out how to output a single one.

Comment: I need the raw path, not the list of the helper methods.

Comment: Ah. Well, it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you want or at least somewhere for you to start working on:

```
Rails.application.routes.named_routes.routes[:order_add_item].path.spec.to_s
```

Comment: @waza, if my answer is correct to your question, please accept it so other people would know

Comment: And how to get the URL instead of the path?